# React native loading data from async storage returns undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to load data from Async Storage in react-native. I managed to load all User Data from API to async storage and I was able to display it in UserData(), however when I try to return received data to other components I get:

[Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"]

I assumed data is returned asyncroniously so I tried to await it however then I was getting:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:]
```

I searched this error and all I found out was that it assumes I was calling hooks in class. It is not truth however, because I simply used setState() in UserProfile() to save data received from UserData(). Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks for all the help in advance.

Function I used to retrieve user data from:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import storage from "./Storage";

export default function UserData() {
  const [userData, setuserData] = useState();

  storage
    .load({
      key: "user",
      autoSync: true,
      syncInBackground: true,
    })
    .then(ret => {
      setuserData(JSON.stringify(ret.info));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // console.warn(err.message);
      return;
    });
  if (userData) return userData;
}
```

Function which displays user profile:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DeleteUser from "./DeleteProfile";
import PayPal from "../navigation/PayPal";
import { Button, TextInput, Text, ScrollView, View, Image } from "react-native";
import Styles from "../../styles/Styles";
import storage from "../elements/Storage";
import UserData from "../elements/GetUserData";

export default function UserProfile() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [premium, setpremium] = useState(false);
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState(false);
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [checkout, setCheckout] = useState(false);
  const info = UserData();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const result = JSON.parse(info);
      setEmail(result.email);
      setName(result.name);
      setId(result._id);
      setPhone(result.phone);
      setpremium(result.premium);
      setAdmin(result.admin);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView style={Styles.userProfile}>
      <View style={(Styles.bigBar, { textAlign: "center" })}>
        <Text style={Styles.h1}>Profile Page</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={Styles.profileContent}>
        <View>
          <Image
            style={Styles.profileImg}
            source={{
              uri: "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/8b/16/7a/8b167af653c2399dd93b952a48740620.jpg",
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <View style={Styles.profileView}>
              <Text style={Styles.h6}>User name: </Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View>
            <View style={Styles.profileView}>
              <Text style={Styles.h6}>Email: </Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View>
            <View style={Styles.profileView}>
              <Text style={Styles.h6}>Phone number: </Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View>
            {/* {premium && ( */}
            <View style={Styles.profileView}>
              <Text style={Styles.h6}>premium: </Text>
            </View>
            {/* )} */}
          </View>
          <View>
            {/* {!premium && ( */}
            <View style={Styles.profileView}>
              <Text style={Styles.h6}> premium: </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                }}
              ></View>
            </View>
            {/* )} */}
          </View>

          {/* {admin && ( */}
          <View style={Styles.profileView}>
            <Text style={Styles.h6}>Admin: </Text>
            <View style={{ color: "green" }}></View>
          </View>
          {/* )} */}
        </View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <View style={Styles.profileView2}>
              <Text style={Styles.h6}>{name}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View>
            <View style={Styles.profileView2}>
              <Text style={Styles.h6}>{email}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View>
            <View style={Styles.profileView2}>
              <Text style={Styles.h6}>{phone}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View>
            {/* {premium && ( */}
            <View style={Styles.profileView2}>
              <View style={{ color: "orange" }}>
                <Text style={Styles.h6}> POSIADANE</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{ marginBottom: 1 }} />
            </View>
            {/* )} */}
          </View>

          <View>
            {/* {!premium && ( */}
            <View style={Styles.profileView2}>
              <View
                className="inline"
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                }}
              >
                {checkout ? (
                  <View style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                    <PayPal />
                  </View>
                ) : (
                  <View style={Styles.smlBtn}>
                    <Button
                      style={{ marginLeft: 1, marginBottom: 1 }}
                      onPress={() => setCheckout(true)}
                      title="BUY PREMIUM"
                    />
                  </View>
                )}
              </View>
            </View>
            {/* )} */}
          </View>

          {/* {admin && ( */}
          <View style={Styles.profileView2}>
            <View style={{ color: "green" }}>
              <Text style={Styles.h6}> TRUE</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          {/* )} */}
        </View>
      </View>
      <View>
        {/* <DeleteUser id={id} /> */}
        {/* <Link
          className="rf update better"
          to={{
            pathname: `/editProfile/?${id}`,
          }}
        >
          UPDATE
        </Link> */}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: 1. Make sure to always add the language tag for the language you're using to get syntax highlighting. 2. Create a *minimal* reproduction case, don't just dump your entire file. 3. `UserData` is neither a hook nor a function component, and so you can't use `useState` inside it.

Comment: Thank you very much for an answer! Based on your answer I tried to move `useState` to my `UserProfile()` and in there do `setuserData(UserData())`. I also changed `UserData()` to return result of the `storage.load` and in `.then` I did: `ret => return ret.info` but that also returns `undefined`. Could you please give me a little bit more explanation as to how can I fix it?

Comment: please add `storage` code.  Looks like your problem is in `storage.load ...` that should be refactored to something like `useStorage`

Comment: I did not create theese methods. I am simply using this module for saving and loading data from storage: https://openbase.com/js/react-native-storage. Here is how I load it from storage if it what you were asking for: `storage.save({
        key: "user",
        data: {
          info: result,
        },

        expires: 1000 * 36000,
      });
    DevSettings.reload();`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. In order to execute it properly I had to handle Promise returned from UserData() with then. It looks like this in the end:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      await UserData().then(result => {
        setEmail(result.email);
        setName(result.name);
        setId(result._id);
        setPhone(result.phone);
        setpremium(result.premium);
        setAdmin(result.admin);
      });
    }
    getData();
  }, []);
```